# How to create non-nested multiple records of the same model using one form in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, simple-form

I looked at related questions on Stack Overflow, but I am at a loss trying to figure this one out.

To elucidate,

1. There are three models: `User`, `A` and `B`.
2. `A` contains, let's say, 3 records with the fields `p1_name`, `p1_score`, `p2_name` and `p2_score` for each record. So, `A` looks like

`-----------------------------------------------------------`
`id` `|` `p1_name` `|` `p1_score` `|` `p2_name` `|` `p2_score`
`id` `|` `p1_name` `|` `p1_score` `|` `p2_name` `|` `p2_score`
`id` `|` `p1_name` `|` `p1_score` `|` `p2_name` `|` `p2_score`
`-----------------------------------------------------------`

3. `B` is the model where the the `User` submits his guesses for what `p1_name` and `p2_name` from `A` scored. So, `B` looks like:

`---------------------------------------------------------------------------------`
`id` `|` `user` `|` `a_id` `|` `p1_name` `|` `p1_score_guess` `|` `p2_name` `|` `p2_score_guess`
`id` `|` `user` `|` `a_id` `|` `p1_name` `|` `p1_score_guess` `|` `p2_name` `|` `p2_score_guess`
`id` `|` `user` `|` `a_id` `|` `p1_name` `|` `p1_score_guess` `|` `p2_name` `|` `p2_score_guess`
`---------------------------------------------------------------------------------`

4. `B` `belongs_to` `A` as each record in `B` is uniquely identified by `user` and `a_id` put together.

I need to make a form for model `B`, handled by the `new` action for its controller, using the view `views/B/new.html.erb`.

This needs to be a single form that shows 3 rows each containing:

- `p1_name` from model `A` (as text)
- `p1_score_guess` for model `B` (as number field)
- `p2_name` from model `B` (as text)
- `p2_score_guess` for model `B` (as number field)

Upon submission using one submit button, the above data for each of the 3 records needs to be submitted to the controller, and multiple records of `B` be created.

I have not encountered this kind of requirement in Rails 4.2.5 before, and am not sure how to go about it. I have been trying to do this since two days, first using simple_form, which did not seem to support this (or I am not able to make one), and then the Rails Forms.

It's become tricky for me because I have to show the `p1_name` and `p2_name` from model `A` in the view under the form **as well as** use it also, to populate model `B`. `B`s controller needs to take in both `p1_name`, `p2_name` and `p1_score_guess`, `p2_score_guess`. Since `a_id` is different for each row, that needs to be taken in as well (further making it impossible for me to figure this one out).

Comment: probably you need `form_tag` instead of `form_for`, since the latter is tailored towards working with a single object. In the controller, you need code that creates the different object, and for each such object extracts the relevant info from `params`.

Comment: Why are you storing `p1_name` in both `A` and `B`?

Answer (score 2):

how about:

```
<%= form_for :bs, url: bs_path do |f| %>
  <% @as.each do |a| %>
    <%= f.fields_for "[#{a.id}]", B.new do |afields| %>
      <%= a.p1_name %>
      <%= afields.text_field :p1_score_guess %>
      <%= a.p2_name %>
      <%= afields.text_field :p2_score_guess %>
    <% end -%>
  <% end -%>
  <%= f.submit 'save' %>
<% end -%>
```

And in Controller you iterate through params[:a_s]

```
def create
  bs_params.each do |a_id, b_attributes|
    B.create b_attributes.merge(a_id: a_id, user: current_user)
  end
end
```

with

```
def bs_params
  params.require(:bs).permit(allowed_a_s)
end

def allowed_a_s
  Hash[a_ids.map {|id| [id.to_s, [:p1_score_guess, :p2_score_guess]]}]
end

def a_ids
  A.pluck(:id)
end
```

---

Just to show you my testcase - I assigned for @as:

```
@as = [A.new(id: 1, p1_name: 'p11', p2_name: 'p12'), A.new(id: 2, p1_name: 'p21', p2_name: 'p22'), A.new(id: 3, p1_name: 'p31', p2_name: 'p32')]
```

And set as a_ids static:

```
def a_ids
  %w[1 2 3]
end
```

and got on a debugger for bs_params with inputs 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 for guesses:

```
=> {
  "1"=>{"p1_score_guess"=>"1", "p2_score_guess"=>"2"},
  "2"=>{"p1_score_guess"=>"3", "p2_score_guess"=>"4"},
  "3"=>{"p1_score_guess"=>"5", "p2_score_guess"=>"6"}
}
```

---

Update: Since above code does not check validations, I try again (this time not tested - sorry):

```
<%= form_for :bs, url: bs_path do |f| %>
  <% @bs.each do |a, b| %>
    <%= f.fields_for "[#{a.id}]", b do |afields| %>
      <%= a.p1_name %>
      <%= afields.text_field :p1_score_guess %>
      <%= a.p2_name %>
      <%= afields.text_field :p2_score_guess %>
    <% end -%>
  <% end -%>
  <%= f.submit 'save' %>
<% end -%>
```

And in controller do:

```
def new
  @bs = Hash[a_ids.map { |a_id| [a_id, B.new] }]
end

def create
  @bs = {}
  bs_params.each do |a_id, b_attributes|
    @bs[a_id] = B.new b_attributes.merge(a_id: a_id, user: current_user)
  end
  @bs.values.each(&:valid?) # to ensure, all errors are assigned - and not finding one will stop to check for any other
  if @bs.values.all?(&:valid?)
    @bs.values.each &:save
    redirect_to root_path
  else
    render :new
  end
end
```

and bs_params, allowod_a_s and a_ids as above

Comment: Thank you @bpieck, brilliant answer, very clear. I was looking for something similar and with minor changes it worked for me.

Comment: the only thing that is not working for me is the original validates on the fields of the class, for example, if one field requires presence, is ignoring that validation. Did I make a mistake?

Comment: You mean, it's not shown? Or they are really ignored and instances are created, although they should be invalid?
Last sounds weired, since create checks validations. If you mean first: Yes, you are right. this code did not even check for invalid bs, to know to render :new again. Of course it is possible - some more effort. I can try to update my answer for that case later the day.

Comment: Above changes still do not check, if any before_save stopped saving - but I think it should work your case.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. What was happening is that it was creating the records on the database ignoring the validation. For me it was also strange since it uses the create.